# The disabled formatting is jumping around each checkbox. What is happening?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing up a form that has various options with time slots where users can select a window that they works for them. When they select an option that shares the same time frame with another option, the other options are supposed to be disabled until the user deselects the option they clicked. This way they cannot select two options with conflicting times.

The problems I'm running into are:

1. The options are not re-enabling when a user deselects the checkbox they clicked.
2. When a user selects a different checkbox, the disabled formatting jumps around to the other options.

What could be causing this to happen?

```js
const activityCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.activities input');
const activityLabels = document.querySelectorAll('.activities label')

document.querySelector('.activities').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const clicked = e.target;
    const clickedTime = clicked.getAttribute('time');

    for (let i = 0; i < activityCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        const activityTime = activityCheckboxes[i].getAttribute('time');
        if (clickedTime === activityTime && clicked !== activityCheckboxes[i]) {
            activityCheckboxes[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
            activityLabels[i].style.color = "gray";
            activityLabels[i].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
        } else {
            activityCheckboxes[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
            activityLabels[i].style.setProperty("color", "initial");
            activityLabels[i].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "initial");
        }
    }


});
```

```html
<fieldset class="activities">
        <legend>Different Time Options</legend>
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 1  - 3pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="1pm"> Option 2 - 1pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="4pm"> Option 3 - 4pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="1pm"> Option 4 - 1pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 5 - 3pm </label>   
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 6 - 3pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="4pm"> Option 7 - 4pm </label>
                    
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not check if your inputs are checked or not so only one action happens for both cases.
2. You only check the one input that triggered the event so all the styling/disabling for the other inputs is lost

The snippet below clears all the items then check which ones should be disabled and disables those

```js
const activityCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.activities input');
const activityLabels = document.querySelectorAll('.activities label')

document.querySelector('.activities').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const clicked = document.querySelectorAll('.activities input:checked');
    let selector = 'xxx ';
    for (let i = 0; i < clicked.length; i++) {
        selector += ',.activities [time="'+clicked[i].getAttribute('time')+'"]:not(:checked)';
    }
    const clickedTime = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let i = 0; i < activityCheckboxes.length; i++) {
            activityCheckboxes[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
            activityLabels[i].style.setProperty("color", "initial");
            activityLabels[i].style.setProperty("text-decoration", "initial");
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < clickedTime.length; i++) {
            clickedTime[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
            clickedTime[i].style.color = "gray";
            clickedTime[i].parentElement.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }


});
```

```html
<fieldset class="activities">
        <legend>Different Time Options</legend>
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 1  - 3pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="1pm"> Option 2 - 1pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="4pm"> Option 3 - 4pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="1pm"> Option 4 - 1pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 5 - 3pm </label>   
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="3pm"> Option 6 - 3pm </label>
          <br />
          <label><input type="checkbox" time="4pm"> Option 7 - 4pm </label>
                    
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: How exactly does this code work? Is there a name for it?

let selector = 'xxx ';
for (let i = 0; i < clicked.length; i++) {
        selector += ',.activities [time="'+clicked[i].getAttribute('time')+'"]:not(:checked)';
    }

I'd like to learn more and make sure I'm understanding the logic.

Comment: It's building a selector to select all the input to disable i.e. all the unchecked inputs with matching time attribute, the xxx is just a dummy so I didn't have to do a comma check inside the loop.